# MVEL VerifyError with Bulk Update - Not updated few records in JAVA API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search bulk update JAVA API. Below is the script, I am using for bulk update. In mapping nested object 'name' is specified as string field.

```
String updateScript = "if(ctx._source.containsKey(\"nestedObjects\") && ctx._source.nestedObjects.size()>0)
{
    int nestedSize = ctx._source.nestedObjects.size();
    boolean isUpdated = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nestedSize; i++)
    {
        if(ctx._source.nestedObjects[i].containsKey(\"name\"))
        {
            if(ctx._source.nestedObjects[i].name == \"ram\")
            {
                ctx._source.nestedObjects[i].name = \"ricky\";
                isUpdated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!isUpdated)
    {
        ctx._source.nestedObjects.add(\"name\":\"ricky\");
    }
}";
```

Below is the code I am using for bulk update.

```
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = client.prepareBulk();


    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
            String documentId = String.value(i);
            bulkRequestBuilder.add(indexName, type, documentId).setScript(updateScript).setRouting(routingName).request());
    }

    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Bulk Failure Message:

```
message [VerifyError[(class: ASMAccessorImpl_2153668671377692494610, method: getValue signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/elasticsearch/common/mvel2/integration/VariableResolverFactory;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Expecting to find integer on stack]]
```

Note : Only few records not getting updated. If I update again, some other few records getting same error and not updated. The record, which got error for the first time got updated in second time.

Comment: Does the first code snippet even compile? I see that you are calling `size()` on `nestedObjects` like it is some sort of `Collection`, but then, further down,  you are trying to access the elements like it is some sort of array?

Comment: This is an update script. Its actually a sting variable. Elastic search will accept this.